# How can I show that the Lucas numbers are given by the sum of $F_{k-1}+F_{k+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I was wondering how I can show that the Lucas numbers are also given by the formula $F_{k-1}+F_{k+1}$ in terms of Fibonacci numbers. I got the formula for the Lucas numbers to be $L_k=[\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{5})]^k+[\frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt{5})]^k$ and I know the recurrence relation is just the sum of the two previous numbers (i.e. $L_k=L_{k-1}+L_{k-2}$), but I cannot seem to get how to use this information to show that $L_k=F_{k-1}+F_{k+1}$.

Comment: The recurrence relation for Fibonacci and Lucas numbers is the same hence $L_k=F_{k-1}+F_{k+1}$ can be simply proved by induction on $k$.

Comment: I know, but I didn't manage to show, using the formulas for both Lucas and Fibonacci, that $L_k=F_{k-1}+F_{k+1}$. How would the algebra work out?

Comment: Also, I'm guessing you're using strong induction?

Comment: If $L_k=F_{k-1}+F_{k+1}$ and $L_{k+1}=F_k+F_{k+2}$ then $L_{k+2}=F_{k+1}+F_{k+3}$. I am using strong induction, yes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sure, we could use the closed forms for the sequences:
\begin{align}
L_n &= \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n + \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n\\
F_n &= \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left[ \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n - \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n \right]
\end{align}

So a bit of algebra:
\begin{align}
F_{n-1}+F_{n+1}
&= \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left[ \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n-1} - \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n-1} \right] + \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left[ \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n+1} - \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n+1} \right]\\
&=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[ \left(1+\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2\right) \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n-1} - \left(1+\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2\right)\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n-1}  \right]\\
&=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[ \left(\sqrt{5}\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right) \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n-1} - \left(\sqrt{5}\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n-1}  \right]\\
&=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n + \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n
= L_n
\end{align}

Comment: Why the downvotes? It ain't pretty but it's valid given the assumptions of the OP.

Comment: I gave the down-vote because it's unnecessarily complicated. You should know that $\varphi,\psi=(1\pm\sqrt{5})/2$; then it would be a lot easier to follow. In addition, $F_n=\frac{\varphi^n-\psi^n}{\varphi-\psi}$ and $L_n=\varphi^n+\psi^n$.

Comment: A down vote for a correct answer with a bit of explicit calculation seems absurd, but each to their own I suppose.